# Android Development, writing code to work with number pickers

Tags: java, android

Recently I've started taking a Mobile Development class at my University which is a newer class and, unfortunately, my professor tends to stumble through material sometimes and while I do my best to keep up with I've gotten a little lost with the fundamentals and was hoping to have a few things cleared up.  Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

The first project we have is to create a simple app that uses three number pickers to pick a value for red, a value for blue, and a value for green and use these values to change the color of a window or just the background.  I understand the code for the app would be to set a color background and pass in the three picked numbers to make the color of the background.

What I am having issues with is working with the code for the number pickers themselves.  In the java side main I feel like I should have a method to set up the pickers and use the pickers ID to identify them in the java main(?).  I'm not sure what to write for this method or how to structure it or where to start with the project really.

So far I have the SDK working eclipse with the preloaded "hello world" app working on my android device.  Also have a new android project and three number pickers put on the XML lay out.  Again, I need to have the three number pickers each pick a value (RGB respectively) and have those values set the RGB color of a background.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I would prefer to not have the answer given to me directly I would like to actually learn this and be able to work with it in the future, I am just looking for maybe someone to converse with to make sure I have a grasp on the material and fundamentals or at the very least enough information to be able to get to where I need myself.  Any advice, tips, or links to maybe a tutorial would be outstanding.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Best way to get help here is to attempt your project on your own, then post your code attempt here along with an explanation of what isn't working or what exact part you can't do. One of the keys here is you should be pointing only only a small problem. Right now this question is pretty vague and broad.

Answer (score 0):

So in your layout you have 3 number pickers. Assign all of them ids in the layout so that you can reference them in your activity.

In your activity you have to initialize 3 NumberPicker elements. For example

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private NumberPicker red;
private NumberPicker green;
private NumberPicker blue;

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

setContentView(R.id.yourlayout);
red = findViewById(R.id.redId)... and so on

}

}
```

Then, since you want them to be RGB values, you can use the setMaxValue(int) and setMinValue(int) to control their ranges (think of the range of RGB colors).

Then you need to listen for the value of each number picker to change right and create the new color and then set the background for your view or your window.

To do that, just get the values from your number pickers and create a new color object (see the documentation for specifics)

[NumberPicker Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html)
and the [Color Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

You should be able to figure out the specifics from there.